# TypeError: editProfile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'obj'

Tags: python, forms, flask, edit

I want to edit my user profile, here is my model, the form and view. After the transfer of 'obj' to form (in view) this message appears:

> "TypeError: editProfile() got an unexpected keyword argument 'obj'"

Please for hint.

Model:

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    age = db.Column(db.Integer, index=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.name)
```

Form:

```
class editProfile(Form):
    name = StringField('name', validators=[DataRequired()])
    age = IntegerField('age', validators=[DataRequired()])
    email = StringField('email', validators=[Email()])
```

View:

```
@app.route('/edit/<int:id>')
def editProfile(id):
    post = User.query.get(id)
    form = editProfile(obj=post)
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        form.populate_obj(post)
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Profile was updated")
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('editProfile.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling the `editProfile` function, not the class, ie, you're doing recursion.
Your `editProfile` function does not take any arguments named `obj` therefore you're getting that error.
This is because they are named exactly the same.

Change to

```
def editProfile(id):
  post = User.query.get(id)
  form = EditProfileForm(obj=post)
```

And you'll see that it'll work.